# Generic usage with inner class problems

Tags: java, generics

I am not posting the entire code. I have this:

```
public class LinkedList2<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<T> {

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private int numOfElem;

    private class Node<T> {

        Node<T> next;
        T data;

        Node(Node<T> next, T data) {
            this.next = next;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    private class LinkedList2Iterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
            private int count = LinkedList2.this.numOfElem;
            private Node<T> current = LinkedList2.this.head;
    }
}
```

On `javac -Xlint LinkedList2.java` I get this error:

```
LinkedList2.java:134: incompatible types
found   : LinkedList2<T>.Node<T>
required: LinkedList2<T>.Node<T>
        private Node<T> current = LinkedList2.this.head;
                                              ^
1 error
```

Can you help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java generics type parameter hiding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512627/java-generics-type-parameter-hiding) and [Custom Java Iterator with type confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290611/custom-java-iterator-with-type-confusion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define your inner class `LinkedList2Iterator`, you've made it generic with another `<T>` generic type parameter.  That `<T>` doesn't match the `<T>` from the outer class `LinkedList2`.

```
private class LinkedList2Iterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
```

You don't need to declare another `<T>` here, just use the `<T>` from the outer class, which is still in scope:

```
private class LinkedList2Iterator implements Iterator<T> {
```

Comment: Aha! thanks. But what about the T in Iterator<T> ? That does not conflict with T in LinkedList2<T>?

Comment: The `<T>` in `Iterator<T>` doesn't conflict with `LinkedList2<T>`, because it simply uses the `<T>` defined in `LinedList2<T>`.