# Custom Generic LinkedList with Inner Nodes and Iterator in Java: Type Confusion

Tags: java, generics, iterator

I thought I was getting the hang of generics until I came across [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/code/LinkedList.java) (a basic implementation of a Generic LinkedList with inner Node and Iterator classes. A clipped version of code linked pasted below).

**Q:** Why is it that we have `LinkedListIterator` and not `LinkedListIterator<AnyType>`

**A:** See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17375431/629000).

Fine. Makes sense. But then,

**Q:** Why is it that we have `Node<AnyType>` and not `Node`? Since the Node class is also within the scope of `LinkedList`, from the last answer, I would expect that Node also would not require  in its definition.

```
public class LinkedList<AnyType> implements Iterable<AnyType>
{
   private Node<AnyType> head;

//...

   private static class Node<AnyType>
   {
      private AnyType data;
      private Node<AnyType> next;

      public Node(AnyType data, Node<AnyType> next)
      {
         this.data = data;
         this.next = next;
      }
   }

   public Iterator<AnyType> iterator()
   {
      return new LinkedListIterator();
   }

   private class LinkedListIterator  implements Iterator<AnyType>
   {
      private Node<AnyType> nextNode;

      public LinkedListIterator()
      {
         nextNode = head;
      }
//...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is due to the scope of the generic type parameter for a class.  It's in scope for every non-`static` member, including inner classes, but not `static` nested classes.

Therefore, `LinkedList`'s `AnyType` type parameter is in scope for the inner class `LinkedListIterator`, and it doesn't have to declare it.  Additionally, `AnyType` is not in scope for the `static` nested class `Node`, so it needs to have its own type parameter (it didn't have to be named the same).